# Remove Specific Array Element, Equal to String - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, element

Is there no easy way to remove a specific element from an array, if it is equal to a given string? The workarounds are to find the index of the element of the array you wish to remove, and then `removeAtIndex`, or to create a new array where you append all elements that are not equal to the given string. But is there no quicker way?

Comment: Have you looked at the methods in the NSMutableArray class reference, like removeObject:, or removeObjectIdenticalTo:?

Comment: I am using swift, and the way I find out what I can do with an array, is to put a dot after its name and see what options xcode suggests, these include removeAll, removeAtIndex, removeLast, and removeRange. I can't see any reference to removeObjectIdenticalTo.

Comment: Your question didn't specify whether you were referring to a Swift Array or an NSMutableArray; you can use ether in Swift. If you're programming in Swift, you won't see the NSMutableArray suggestions unless you cast your array to an NSMutableArray

Comment: Thanks, I only started programming a month ago so that is very helpful

Answer (score 158, accepted):

**You can use filter() to filter your array as follow**

```
var strings = ["Hello","Playground","World"]

strings = strings.filter { $0 != "Hello" }

print(strings)   // "["Playground", "World"]\n"
```

**edit/update:**

**Xcode 10 • Swift 4.2 or later**

You can use the new `RangeReplaceableCollection` mutating method called `removeAll(where:)`

```
var strings = ["Hello","Playground","World"]

strings.removeAll { $0 == "Hello" }

print(strings)   // "["Playground", "World"]\n"
```

If you need to remove only the first occurrence of an element we ca implement a custom remove method on `RangeReplaceableCollection` constraining the elements to `Equatable`:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: Equatable {
    @discardableResult
    mutating func removeFirst(_ element: Element) -> Element? {
        guard let index = firstIndex(of: element) else { return nil }
        return remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

---

Or using a predicate for non `Equatable` elements:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    @discardableResult
    mutating func removeFirst(where predicate: @escaping (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Element? {
        guard let index = try firstIndex(where: predicate) else { return nil }
        return remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

---

```
var strings = ["Hello","Playground","World"]
strings.removeFirst("Hello")
print(strings)   // "["Playground", "World"]\n"
strings.removeFirst { $0 == "Playground" }
print(strings)   // "["World"]\n"
```

Answer (score 18):

Using filter like suggested above is nice. But if you want to remove only one occurrence of a value or you assume there are no duplicates in the array and you want a faster algorithm, use this:

**EDIT: Swift 5 Update**

```
if let index = array.firstIndex(of: "stringToRemove") {
    array.remove(at: index)
} else {
    // not found
}
```

Thanks @Thomas Mary.

**Swift 3 and 4**

```
if let index = array.index(of: "stringToRemove") {
    array.remove(at: index)
} else {
    // not found
}
```

Comment: Swift 5 update :        
`if let index = array.firstIndex(of: "stringToRemove") {
    array.remove(at: index)
}`

Answer (score 9):

It's not clear if by quicker you mean in terms of execution time or amount of code.

In the latter case you can easily create a copy using the `filter` method. For example, given the following array:

```
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

you can create a copy with all elements but "2" as:

```
let filteredArray = array.filter { $0 != "2" }
```

Comment: Hahaha we are in perfect sync but i was 7 seconds faster. :)

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus: Haha, yes, but I was interrupted by my wife asking me a question while writing the answer... so I won ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is essentially what I have been doing, by using a for loop to go through the array and append the element to another array if it is not equal to the string I wish to remove, and when I said quicker, you're right I just mean looks tidier in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to use `filter()`.  If you have a single element (called say `obj`) to remove, then the `filter()` predicate will be `{ $0 != obj }`.  If you do this repeatedly for a large array this might be a performance issue.  If you can defer removing individual objects and want to remove an entire sub-array then use something like:

```
var stringsToRemove : [String] = ...
var strings : [String] = ...

strings.filter { !contains(stringsToRemove, $0) }
```

for example:

```
 1> ["a", "b", "c", "d"].filter { !contains(["b", "c"], $0) }
$R5: [String] = 2 values {
  [0] = "a"
  [1] = "d"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**You could use filter() in combination with operator overloading to produce an easily repeatable solution**:

```
func -= (inout left: [String], right: String){
    left = left.filter{$0 != right}    
}

var myArrayOfStrings:[String] = ["Hello","Playground","World"]

myArrayOfStrings -= "Hello"

print(myArrayOfStrings)   // "[Playground, World]"
```

Answer (score 2):

if you need to delete subArray from array then this is a perfect solution using **Swift3**:

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]            
let subArrayToDelete = ["c", "d", "e", "ee"]
array = array.filter{ !subArrayToDelete.contains($0) }
print(array) // ["a", "b", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
```

this is better for your performance rather than deleting one by one.

btw even **faster** solution is (but it will rearrange items in the final array):

```
array = Array(Set(array).subtracting(subArrayToDelete))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var ra = ["a", "ab", "abc", "a", "ab"]

print(ra)                               // [["a", "ab", "abc", "a", "ab"]

ra.removeAll(where: { $0 == "a" })

print(ra)                               // ["ab", "abc", "ab"]
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as  `removeAll { $0 == "a" }`

Answer (score 0):

Simple loop over Array

```
var array = ["Apple","Banana","Orange"]

for (index,value) in array.enumerated(){
    if value == "Banana"{
    array.remove(at: index)
}
```

Comment: you can't remove an item from a non mutable collection

Comment: Thanks Buddy @LeoDabus for correcting  me i have changed from let to var now you able to do it

Answer (score 0):

One small point.

Normally you must simply use `.filter{$0 != target}`

If for some reason you wish to traverse the array. It's a basic of programming that you DON'T edit/delete items from an array while you're traversing it as, depending on the exact nature of the language/OS/etc it may or may not result in unpredictable behavior for the obvious reasons.

The only safe way to traverse is (in some cases) backwards but (always) using a while formulation which re-looks at the array each pass:

```
    while let found = urls.firstIndex(of: target) {
        urls.remove(at: found)
    }
```

This is a basic of working with arrays.

Again, always use `.filter{$0 != target}`

As a footnote, in the incredible case that it is a performance issue (literally 10s of millions of entries), you'd handle the whole thing completely differently using indices and so on, so it is totally irrelevant to this question.