# Remove specific object from array in swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift3

[image: Remove Object From Array Swift 3]

I have a problem trying to remove a specific object from an array in Swift 3. I want to remove item from an array as in the screenshot but I don't know the solution.

If you have any solutions please share with me.

Comment: Please post actual code in your question, not an image.

Comment: you need to specify at which index the object is.

Comment: Please read the documentation for `Array`. It shows examples of adding and removing objects to/from an array.

Answer (score 37):

**Short Answer**

you can find the index of object in array then remove it with index.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
var itemToRemove = 4
if let index = array.index(of: itemToRemove) {
    array.remove(at: index)
}
```

**Long Answer**

if your array elements confirm to Hashable protocol you can use

```
array.index(of: itemToRemove)
```

because Swift can find the index by checking hashValue of array elements.

but if your elements doesn't confirm to Hashable protocol or you don't want find index base on hashValue then you should tell *index* method how to find the item. so you use index(where: ) instead which asks you to give a predicate clouser to find right element

```
// just a struct which doesn't confirm to Hashable
struct Item {
    let value: Int
}

// item that needs to be removed from array
let itemToRemove = Item(value: 4)

// finding index using index(where:) method
if let index = array.index(where: { $0.value == itemToRemove.value }) {

    // removing item
    array.remove(at: index)
}
```

> if you are using index(where:) method in lots of places you can define a predicate function and pass it to index(where:)

```
// predicate function for items
func itemPredicate(item: Item) -> Bool {
    return item.value == itemToRemove.value
}

if let index = array.index(where: itemPredicate) {
    array.remove(at: index)
}
```

for more info please read Apple's developer documents:

[index(where:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688966-index)

[index(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689674-index)

Comment: Why bother with `array.contains`? Just get the index.

Comment: just to be sure :D but yes you can remove array.contains and just use if let index = array.index(of : itemToRemove)

Comment: @Mohammadalijf You don't need `array.contains(itemToRemove)` just  `if  let index = array.index(of: itemToRemove)` is enough

Comment: @Socheat It's right there in the documentation for the Swift Array class. `index(of:)`.

Answer (score 20):

According to your code, the improvement could be like this:

```
    if let index = arrPickerData.index(where: { $0.tag == pickerViewTag }) {
        arrPickerData.remove(at: index)
        //continue do: arrPickerData.append(...)
    }
```

The index existing means Array contains the object with that Tag.

Comment: @Socheat, ，the more you use Swift, the more you feel it powerful!

Comment: Yes, I think so bro.

Answer (score 6):

I used the solutions provided here: [Remove Specific Array Element, Equal to String - Swift Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878798/remove-specific-array-element-equal-to-string-swift/)

this is one of the solutions there (in case the object was a string):

```
myArrayOfStrings = ["Hello","Playground","World"]
myArrayOfStrings = myArrayOfStrings.filter{$0 != "Hello"}
print(myArrayOfStrings)   // "[Playground, World]"
```