# How can I access values of [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] in Swift 4?

Tags: swift

I am new in Swift. I wish to access the **`sourceApplication`** value inside the `options` parameter of this method.

```
optional func application(_ app: UIApplication, 
                     open url: URL, 
                  options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

I checked [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationopenurloptionskey) and I found out that `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey` is a structure. It contains a type property: `static let sourceApplication: UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey`

But when I tried to access the `sourceApplication` value by doing this:

```
options.sourceApplication
```

...this error was thrown:

> Value of type '`[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]`' has no member '`sourceApplication`'

I have a thought that this might be a dictionary, But the type of the key is `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey`. I don't have any idea how to access the value using the key type `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey`.

I checked out tutorials point and some other sites, but didn't find a solution.

My questions are:

1. How do I access the value named `sourceApplication` from `options`?
2. What do you call this type of parameter? (`[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]`)? Is this a dictionary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE for Swift 4.2**

The method was changed to:

```
func open(_ url: URL, 
          options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:], 
          completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

You can access the keys in the same way.

---

`options` is a **dictionary**. You should access the `sourceApplication` **key** of it.

```
if let sourceApp = options[.sourceApplication] as? String {
    //work with the value
}
```

[From Apple's documentation about `sourceApplication`:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/openurloptionskey/1623128-sourceapplication)

> Contains the bundle ID of the app that sent the open-URL request to your app. Value is an `NSString` object.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer! Now I understand how it's done. But may I ask what = [:] this means?

Comment: Means the default it is an empty dictionary

Comment: Note that UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey is redundant. (Not necessary) `[.sourceApplication]`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you, I am aware of that, I wrote it like this deliberately. (it's easier for a beginner to see it through this way)

Comment: @RandomForkson Leo Dabus is right, it's the default value of the `options` argument. To learn more about Swift functions, take a look at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).

Comment: The comment was aimed at the OP

Comment: @RandomForkson you might be interested in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492353/ios-copying-files-from-inbox-folder-to-document-path